# When I use order-date in youtube api then there are total results but items are not found

Tags: youtube-api

When I use order-date in youtube api then there are total results but items not found.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2C+snippet&maxResults=50&publishedBefore=2006-06-10T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&q=Narendra+Modi&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2C+snippet&maxResults=50&order=date&publishedBefore=2006-06-10T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&q=Narendra+Modi&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

These two links give different results.

Comment: I believe it's because when you use `order` or publish date, you might be getting results that are technically what you asked for, but not relevant enough based on YouTube's implementation. So even though there are results that would fit your criteria, the API doesn't think they're relevant enough to show you.