# Youtube data api v3 not working as expected

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

I am using search api for youtube :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

I get total of 40191 records and per page I have set max 50.

But I get 17 results every time.

These are the options I am using for getting records:

```
// SET OPTIONS FOR API
$optionsArray = array(
        'q' => $_GET['q'],
        'maxResults' => 50,
        'order' => 'date',
        'type' => 'video'
    );

// Send request
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id, snippet', $optionsArray);
```

Also setting `pageToken` doesnt work. Records are same even after applying `nextPageToken`.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: What you are passing to `q`?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 keyword.

Comment: exact value of `q`? Can you show the whole code (with removed API key)?

Comment: "hardwell%20singles" is the exact value.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you get only 17 results is the `order` property of your request. If you remove this property you get many more results. The `order='date'` is not working as expected.

**A little workaround (only example):**

```
$DEVELOPER_KEY = 'THEKEY';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

//Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

try {
    // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
    // query term.
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
        'q' => $_GET['q'],
        'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
        'type' => 'video'
    ));

    function sortResponse($date1, $date2) {
        $date1 = new DateTime($date1['snippet']['publishedAt']);
        $date2 = new DateTime($date2['snippet']['publishedAt']);
        //"<" - sort DESC
        //">" - sort ASC
        return $date1 < $date2;
    }

    $items = $searchResponse['items'];
    usort($items, "sortResponse");

    //now your sorted items are in $items...
}
```

You can merge all your repsonse items in one array and use the custom sort function to get the order by `publishAt`.

> **API Document:**
> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=de#parameters
>
> **Related Question:**
> [When I use order-date in youtube api then there are total results but items are not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250188/when-i-use-order-date-in-youtube-api-then-there-are-total-results-but-items-are)